# Svelte component register each finger as a separate touch event

Tags: svelte, multi-touch

I have instances of a Svelte component inside a loop and I want to be able to slide the .box element of each Slider component independently with more than one fingers at the same time.

Here's a reduced version of the code (couldn't include it in a REPL):
https://github.com/dtsmarin/svelteSOexample

EDIT: I think my use of svelte-motion here causes more problems than it solves. I'm in the process of replacing it with something simpler like Hammer.js. In any case If someone has got a solution I'm still interested.

Comment: Questions should be self-contained. If you have relevant code reduce it and include it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach here should be to use pointer events which provide a `pointerId` that can be used to identify the finger. You can use capture functions to prevent interference between fingers and to keep sliding a slider until the finger is released, even if the finger accidentally left the slider's area during the interaction.

Example:

```html
<script>
  let element;
  
  let capturedPointerId = null;
  let x = 0;
  let y = 0;

  function onPointerDown(e) {
    element.setPointerCapture(e.pointerId);
    capturedPointerId = e.pointerId;
  }
  function onPointerUp(e) {
    capturedPointerId = null;
    element.releasePointerCapture(e.pointerId);
  }
  function onPointerMove(e) {
    if (capturedPointerId != e.pointerId)
      return;

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    x += e.movementX;
    y += e.movementY;
  }
</script>

<div bind:this={element}
     on:pointerdown={onPointerDown}
     on:pointerup={onPointerUp}
     on:pointermove={onPointerMove}
     style:transform="translate({x}px, {y}px)">
  {capturedPointerId}
</div>

<style>
  div {
    /* This is important to prevent panning/zooming/reload gestures. */
    touch-action: none;
  }
</style>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/f4d47ab5a8294f5c866a3d829b37d3f0?version=3.50.1)

Comment: Thank you. This solution worked really great! Here's the modified version to suit my needs better https://svelte.dev/repl/634f9cdcd8b04ed28818dbdcc0a7c925?version=3.50.1